# Windows 8 Not Shutting Down Properly

Tags: windows-8, shutdown

**New question specifically regarding this: [Windows 8 Not Shutting Down Properly With Fast Start-Up Enabled](https://superuser.com/questions/505946/windows-8-doesnt-shutdown-properly-with-fast-start-up-enabled)** *(somewhat solved)*

---

Since installing Windows 8, the computer hasn't been shutting down properly. When selecting to power down, the PC quickly displays the shutting down screen, the monitor powers off, and the computer remains on but unresponsive. After about 5 minutes, the computer will turn off. Upon booting into windows again, I am informed that Windows didn't properly shut down.

I'm running a fast SSD, and it's a clean install of Windows 8, so there's no way Windows is taking that time to do some sort of hibernate on shutdown or whatever - not to mention the error when entering Windows the next time.

This happens on every shut down. Restart works as expected.

EDIT: Formatting again didn't work. Fails regardless of drivers installed.

---

```
Event viewer
```

Always these two messages in close succession:

Error (event ID 6008): The previous system shutdown at 7:45:21 PM on ‎27/‎10/‎2012 was unexpected.

Critical (kernel power, event ID 41): The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

Comment: could you see if there's anything in event viewer that may be of interest?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek see edit

Comment: Have you checked device manager for missing drivers. From what I've read Windows 8 doesn't actually shutdown, but does something more like hibernation. Did you do Windows Update?

Comment: Doesn't shut down with standard slew of mobo drivers installed or not. Fresh installs both times. Windows Update has been run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching off [Fast Startup](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: Certainly worked. Don't know if related, but BIOS stated my graphics card doesn't support UEFI GOP and thus 'Ultra Fast Boot'.

Comment: Try updating your drivers

Comment: Btw, is it possible to hibernate your PC? If hibernation doesn't work, Fast Startup won't work as well

Comment: If hibernate is sleep, it works (Fast Startup is off)

Comment: Hibernate is different from sleep. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/Sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions

Comment: Ah yep, had to enable it. Works as well, got some graphical glitches across the screen on wake though. Again, Fast Startup is disabled.

Comment: I really don't understand how hibernation works and Fast Startup doesn't. Try posting this question on http://www.eightforums.com and http://answers.microsoft.com Also, contact Microsoft Support at http://support.microsoft.com 

Fast Startup is one awesome feature.

Comment: Is the feature dependent upon UEFI compatible hardware?

Comment: No, BIOS will do. I'm using it. Mine is not UEFI compatible. Just BIOS

Comment: Mind expanding on why this matters?

Comment: Why what matters? Didn't get you there

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to **Tweaking with Vishal** in his article entitled *"Fix Windows 8 Restart and Shutdown Problems by Disabling “Hybrid Shutdown” Feature"*, computer systems hang while rebooting or shutting down the system.

Most of the times these kind of issues are related with the new "Hybrid Shutdown" feature introduced in Windows 8. Hybrid shutdown feature of Windows 8 decreases the total startup time by hibernating the kernel session instead of closing it which reduces the overall Windows loading time because resuming from hibernated system session is very less work compared to a full system initialization.

But this new feature is causing problems to some computer systems and if you are also facing reboot or shutdown problems in Windows 8, you can fix it by disabling this new hybrid shutdown feature and doing a complete shutdown.

The simple steps to accomplish this are provided:

http://www.askvg.com/fix-windows-8-restart-and-shutdown-problems-by-disabling-hybrid-shutdown-feature/

Comment: See accepted answer. Follow link at the end of question.

Comment: @Patrick: OK :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the bonjour service installed, try uninstalling that. I had the same problem, and I solved it by uninstalling the bonjour service.

Comment: No, it wouldn't have been. Fresh install of Windows still had the issue.